# Fast-to-set-up HSQLDB database management GUI

Tags: open-source, database, gui

I am looking for a GUI to quickly check an [HSQL (Hyper SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSQLDB) database.

Requirements:

- Fast to set up
- Can be started from command line with filename as an argument
- See tables
- Run queries
- Open source

Answer (score 2):

The HSQLDB JAR itself actually contains such a manager:

```
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager
```

To open `db.data`:

```
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager --url jdbc:hsqldb:file:db.data
```

It is not the nicest GUI on Earth though:

[image: HSQLDB database manager Ubuntu]

Comment: Later versions have DatabaseManagerSwing instead of DatabaseManager

Answer (score 0):

[LibreOffice Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/) is designed to do *exactly* what you're asking. You can make custom data entry forms, queries, and reports.
If you read [this tutorial](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/0/02/Base_tutorial.pdf) you'll know everything you need.

Comment: Is it compatible with any HSQLDB file, in particular HSQLDB files not created with LibreOffice Base?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: While I haven't actually tried it yet, yes this is supposed to work. It's supposed to work with MySQL and a bunch of other databases too.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: I was actually just working through a part of that tutorial I linked. The form building capabilities are pretty darn good.

Answer (score 0):

Try DBeaver. It is multiplatform and runs under Linux. You may download it for free at the DBeaver Community home page: https://dbeaver.io/.
If are using Ubuntu or Linux Mint, you may install it directly from the "software boutique" or from Flathub.

Comment: Is the CE version 100% open source? What license? Thanks! :-)